# pythonのhmmlearnについて

Tags: python, 機械学習

http://keik-117.hatenablog.com/entry/2016/07/05/213903
こちらのサイトのコードを上から入力していき、

```
X, Z = model.sample(10)
```

を実行したのですが、

```
>>> X
array([[  0.75706838,  -0.1280334 ],
       [ 10.3137587 ,  10.59635189],
...
```

となっているのですが、自分の環境で実行すると、

```
[[ 10.72456536  10.72456536]
 [  0.79450025   0.79450025]
...
```

のように、2つの値が同じになってしまいます。
明らかにサイトの実行結果が正しいと思うのですが、なぜ2つの値が同じになってしまうのでしょうか。

pythonのバージョンは3.6.5, hmmlearnのバージョンは0.2.0です。
原因が分かる方回答お願いします。

Comment: こういう場合は、Warningが出ると思うので、それを見て解決するようにしてください。質問する場合も、Warningがあれば関係するものを内容に加えるようにすると回答がしやすいです。

Comment: "こういう場合は、Warningが出ると思うので"という部分は同意しかねます。間違った結果をWarningなしに表示するバグありライブラリも存在するはずです。

Answer (score 1):

`hmmlearn`は、最近の更新が`PyPI`の方に反映されていません。
GitHubにある最新のものを使用するといいと思います。

基本的には、以下のようにして`git`でクーロンして、`pip`でインストールします。`hmmlearn`には、`setup.py`があるので、`pip`でフォルダーを指定することでインストールすることができます。

```
git clone https://github.com/hmmlearn/hmmlearn
pip3 install ./hnmlearn
```